# Self executing functions in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have used occasionally `(lambda x:<code>)(<some input>)` in python, to preserve my namespace's (within the global namespace or elsewhere) cleanliness.  One issue with the lambda solution is that it is a very limiting construct in terms of what it may contain.

Note: This is a habit from javascript programming

Is this a recommended way of preserving namespace?  If so, is there a better way to implement a self-executing function?

Comment: In what situation do you want to do this where you couldn't just write a separate function and call it?

Comment: For example, if I wanted to string several function calls inside each other, but didn't want to pollute the namespace with a function that would only be called in a specific place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a function A that will be called only in a specific function B, you can define A in B, by which I think the namespace will not be polluted. e.g.,

Instead of :

```
def a_fn():
    //do something
def b_fn():
    //do something
def c_fn():
    b_fn()
    a_fn()
```

You can:

```
def c_fn():
    def a_fn():
        //do something
    def b_fn():
        //do something
    b_fn()
    a_fn()
```

Though I'm not sure if its the pythonic way, I usually do like this.

Comment: I never realized this, coming from a javascript background, but I just realized that python creates namespaces for functions.

Comment: @Justanotherdunce: Functions defined inside a function are simply additional local variables. In effect, this is a little like a namespace.

Comment: However, this is no different from what JavaScript does.

Comment: Isn't there anything like main function like in Java in python that allows self execution?

Comment: this is not solution, because, we must call c_fn()

Answer (score 11):

Regarding the second half of the question

> is there a better way to implement a self-executing function?

The standard way `(<function-expression>)()` is not possible in Python, because there is no way to put a multi-line block into a bracket without breaking Python's fundamental syntax. Nonetheless, Python do recognize the need for using function definitions as expressions and provide [decorators (PEP318)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) as an alternative. PEP318 has an extensive discussion on this issue, in case someone would like to read more.

With decorators, it would be like

```py
evalfn = lambda f: f()

@evalfn
def _():
    print('I execute immediately')
```

Although vastly different syntatically, we shall see that it really is the same: the function definition is anonimous and used as an expression.

Using decorator for self-excuting functions is a bit of overkill, compared to the let-call-del method shown below. However, it may worth a try if there are many self-execution functions, a self-executing function is getting too long, or you simply don't bother naming these self-executing functions.

```py
def f():
    print('I execute immediately')
f()
del f
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't do it. It's a good in JavaScript, but in Python, you haven either lightweight syntax nor a need for it. If you need a function scope, define a function and call it. But very often you don't need one. You may need to pull code apart into multiple function to make it more understandable, but then a name for it helps anyway, and it may be useful in more than one place.

Also, don't worry about adding some more names to a namespace. Python, unlike JavaScript, has proper namespaces, so a helper you define at module scope is not visible in other files by default (i.e. unless imported).